# Chrome Remote Debugging: Scope variables are no populated in the debugger

Tags: android, google-chrome, usb-debugging

2 days ago my chrome remote debugging of my ionic application was working perfectly. Now however with no changes my remote debugging will not display scope variables.

The Scope section of the remote debugger just says: "Not Paused". This appears always, including when the application is paused on a breakpoint.

I am guessing that the issue may be related to the fact I am debugging with source maps. I did a quick debug session vs a normal web page running in chrome on my tablet, and I could see scope variables that way. This leads me to believe it is potentially related to using source maps.

Additionally, there is an error at of the top of the debugger that says:

"Consider disabling Chrome Data Saver while debugging".

I can't say for sure if this error was always there or not, but I don't recall it being there previously.

However, data saver is off on both the PC and the tablet, which seems it should preclude that error from being shown.

I have been searching but I have only found one other thread related to this issue, and it appears it was never resolved. However, the thread matches my issue exactly:

https://github.com/google/WebFundamentals/issues/4463

Attached is a screenshot of the problem in action.

[Debugger screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0JvKG.png)

I can still use the Watch section to see what is going on in my scope variables by typing them in (as you can see in the example screenshot).

Here is the chrome version information off chrome running on my PC:

Google Chrome   65.0.3325.181 (Official Build) (64-bit) (cohort: 65_win_181)
Revision    dc3469be277cc962ba01d9c0cb5bb1a265676c36-refs/branch-heads/3325@{#725}
OS  Windows
JavaScript  V8 6.5.254.41

I have a Galaxy Tab A (2016) with S Pen.

The tablet is running Android version 7.

Any ideas anyone has to figure out what is going would be very appreciated.

Will

Answer (score 0):

Eventually, for reasons I could not figure out, my app lost the ability to speak to my computer over WebSockets altogether.

Running this command seems to have fixed both my original problem and my new problem.

`cordova plugin add cordova-plugin-websocket`

I already had a websocket lib installed, but perhaps this one was better.

I hope that helps anyone else that has gotten stuck with this problem.

Will